# Doubts on SAML and OAUTH

Tags: java, security, oauth, saml, scribe

For sometime now I'm dealing with SAML and oauth. I have few questions and I would like to know if somebody clarifies my doubts -

1. As per my understanding the validity of SAML response depends on the NotOnOrAfter attribute in SAML response as per SAML2 specification.
2. How SP keeps the track of SAML request when SP gets back the response back from IdP? - I think this depends on the InResponseTo attribute in SAML response by IdP as per SAML2 specification.

I also need to know, how can I set the expiry time of OAUTH token. After googling I found that there is one attribute "expires_in" in OAUTH response which tells how long the token will be valid for but I am not sure how to use this using Scribe. I am using scribe to connect to different providers.

Comment: I think that you should move the `OAUTH` part of your question to a separate one. Getting one answer that covers both SAML2 and OAUTH will probably be hard. Stack Overflow generally doesn't work well with multiple-question questions. Please post one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the `NotOnOrAfter` attribute is part of the `Conditions` that decides when and how the response is valid.
2. If the SP needs to keep track of the response, the SP can do that through the `InResponseTo` parameter. Please note that many SAML2 implementations allow *unsolicited* (i.e. Idp initiated) sessions, where the Idp sends a response without ever having recieved an `AuthnRequest` from the SP.

Comment: I still have one doubt:1) In my case IdP makes POST browser call to SP(https://<SPServer>/saml_login, now my SP generates a SAMLResponse which contains InResponseTo attribute in response xml. So, is it possible for an attacker to make multiple POST calls using the same SAMLResponse? if yes then how can I prevent this?

Comment: A conforming SP implementation must ensure that a specific Response message is only used once. Typically that is done by keeping a list of used Ids of response messages until the `NotOnOrAfter` time has passed.

Comment: Do you mean that SP should keep list of used Ids in a cache and the cache expiration time should be same as NotOnOrAfter?